# Gatsby sourceNode does not work with GraphQL arguments

Tags: gatsby, graphql-js

Currently I am trying to pull some data from a API and add to GraphQL using sourceNode and createNode APIs like that:

```
exports.sourceNodes = async ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }) => {
const modules = ['data', 'stuff', 'bananas'];
const modulesResponse = Promise.all(modules.map(async (module) => getModuleData(module)));
const modulesData = await modulesResponse;

const content = Object.fromEntries(modules.map((entries, index) => [entries, modulesData[index]]));

actions.createNode({
    id: createNodeId(modules.join(',')),
    parent: null,
    children: [],
    content,
    internal: {
        type: 'myData',
        mediaType: 'text/html',
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(content)
    }
});
```

When I try to filter this (using GraphiQL) with arguments it does not appear to work:

```
{
  myData(content: {data: {elemMatch: {filterEntry: {eq: "foo"}}}}) {
    content {
      data {
        filterEntry
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It results in this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "myData": {
      "content": {
        "data": [
          {
            "filterEntry": "foo"
          },
          {
            "filterEntry": "bar"
          },
          {
            "filterEntry": "baz"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your graphql syntax is right? I believe filters are always written as `filter: {}` instead of `content: {}`. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#filter

Comment: I am not sure either but when going through the other node gatsby creates, which has the filter option it also does not work

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution for this. The issue is lies is with the data to be filtered are an entry of the content object. Which means they have no NodeId and are not filterable. The solution is to add a `action.createNode` foreach entry coming from the API instead just putting in the bulk.